# Unable to send JSON request to Rest web service

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest, spring-mvc

I am writing a Restful webservice which is intending to accept and return a json

My web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <display-name>cxf</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>cxf</servlet-name>
        <description>Apache CXF Endpoint</description>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>cxf</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping> 
</web-app>
```

My cxf-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
        http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/soap http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/soap.xsd 
        http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd ">

    <import resource="/applicationContext.xml" />

    <jaxrs:server id="isAdaptor" address="/crossover">
        <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
            <ref bean="salesResource" />
        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    </jaxrs:server>

    <bean id="salesResource"    class="com.crossover.resource.SalesResource" />

</beans>
```

My SalesResource

```
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.ResponseBuilder;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import com.crossover.dao.SalesOrderDao;
import com.crossover.model.OrderDTO;
import com.crossover.model.StatusDTO;

@Path("/sales")
public class SalesResource {

    @Autowired
    private SalesOrderDao salesorderDao;

    @POST
    @Path("/processSalesOrder")
    @Produces("application/json")
    @Consumes("application/json")
    public Response processSalesOrder(OrderDTO orderDto) {
        System.out.println("inside processSalesOrder " + orderDto);
        ResponseBuilder responseBuilder =   Response.status(Response.Status.OK);
        StatusDTO smdto = new StatusDTO("200", "SUCCESS");

        return responseBuilder.build();

    }
}
```

OrderDTO.java

```
public class OrderDTO {

    private String customerCode;
    private String productCode;
    private int requiredQty;

    public String getCustomerCode() {
        return customerCode;
    }
    public void setCustomerCode(String customerCode) {
        this.customerCode = customerCode;
    }
    public String getProductCode() {
        return productCode;
    }
    public void setProductCode(String productCode) {
        this.productCode = productCode;
    }
    public int getRequiredQty() {
        return requiredQty;
    }
    public void setRequiredQty(int requiredQty) {
        this.requiredQty = requiredQty;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "OrderDTO [customerCode=" + customerCode + ", productCode="
                + productCode + ", requiredQty=" + requiredQty + "]";
    }
}
```

My client

```
public class RestClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            URL url = new URL(
                    "http://localhost:8080/crossover-1.0.0/crossover/sales/processSalesOrder");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

            String input = "{\"customerCode\":\"customerCode\",\"productCode\":\"productCode\",\"requiredQty\":10}";

            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            os.write(input.getBytes());
            os.flush();

            if (conn.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_CREATED) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                        + conn.getResponseCode());
            }

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    (conn.getInputStream())));

            String output;
            System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
            while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {

                System.out.println(output);
            }

            conn.disconnect();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }
}
```

below is my exception

```
10:31:59.346 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.a.c.j.i.JAXRSInInterceptor - Accept contentType is: */*
10:31:59.348 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.a.c.j.i.JAXRSInInterceptor - Found operation: processSalesOrder
10:31:59.357 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] WARN  o.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils - No message body reader has been found for request class OrderDTO, ContentType : application/json.
10:31:59.390 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] WARN  o.a.c.j.i.WebApplicationExceptionMapper - javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.readFromMessageBody(JAXRSUtils.java:1261)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.processParameter(JAXRSUtils.java:790)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.processParameters(JAXRSUtils.java:749)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.processRequest(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:236)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.handleMessage(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:101)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:271)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:239)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:223)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:203)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:137)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:159)
```

My input json is

```
{
    "customerCode":"customerCode",
    "productCode":"productCode",
    "requiredQty":10
}
```

Comment: I am not sure but i think you have to call the url `http://localhost:8080/crossover-1.0.0/sales/processSalesOrder`

Comment: Another thing, after you fix the 404, you're going to need a no-arg constructor on your DTO

Comment: @peeskillet I removed the constructor. Have added my input json and also the exception I am getting

Comment: I don't use CXF, but using a Maven archetype, they provide in the web.xml Spring's `ContextLoaderListener` as well as the `contextConfigLocation` pointing the spring context file, which kinda makes sense as that's how  a Spring webapp loads it's app context. Though I am not sure if what you're doing makes up for that. Like I said I don't use CXF, but you can give it a shot

Comment: You can check out the archetype I'm talking about `org.apache.cxf.archetype : cxf-jaxrs-service : 3.1.0`

Comment: @peeskillet can you please help me what is your suggested change and where

Comment: Do you know how to create a project from a Maven archetype? Those coordinates I commented point to a Maven archetype. If you don't know how to build a project from an archetype, just google it, I"m pretty sure you'll find it. It's simple command line stuff. An archetype is  a startup project. You can see the configurations. Try and follow it, and see if matching the differences work

Comment: yes I am using maven archtype